# macOS: brew upgrade doesn't upgrade outdated software

Tags: updates, homebrew, macos-mojave

I am used to Debian. But now I have to use a MacBook with macOS 10.14.6 (fresh install) from time to time.

MacOS has no apt-get. So I downloaded and installed brew.

I installed software like:

```
brew cask install firefox
brew cask install iterm2
```

(and some other stuff)

Software works.
Some days later:

```
brew update
```

gave me a list of software with new versions.

```
brew upgrade
```

upgraded iproute2mac 1.2.2 -> 1.2.3

I thought this should have done the same like "apt-get update & upgrade": everything should be up to date.
Later that day I found the news "iterm2 < 3.3.6 is unsave" (CVE-2019-9535).
I thought "I have upgraded. Everything should be ok"
I was proven wrong:

brew cask info iterm2
iterm2: 3.3.6 (auto_updates)
https://www.iterm2.com/
/usr/local/Caskroom/iterm2/3.3.2 (64B)

It is outdated and vulnerable :-(

Fixing that:

brew cask reinstall iterm2

works.

Checking firefox:

```
> brew cask info firefox
firefox: 70.0 (auto_updates)
https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/
/usr/local/Caskroom/firefox/68.0.1 (64B)
```

another outdated software :-(

let's check everything *before* updating firefox:

```
> brew cask outdated
(no results)
```

The brew checking for outdated software doesn't work. brew upgrade doesn't work. It doesn't notice the old iterm2 and both of them do not notice the old firefox.
I have also checked for software updates in the GUI (apple logo > about this mac). But only Safari is listed there.

How can I get "brew upgrade" to detect and upgrade all outdated software?

Bonus question: Under Debian I receive a notification in the GUI when software is outdated. How to receive such a notification for firefox, iterm2 and other software under macOS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using brew to update the packages would have required to update every installed package individually.

Finally I found a solution for this problem. There is a tool called "brew-cask-upgrade" that can handle updates much better: https://github.com/buo/homebrew-cask-upgrade

After installing the tool you only need one simple command and the tool will:

- update brew
- search (and find!) outdated packages
- update those packages

Here is a small example how to use it and how it is working:

```
$ brew cu
==> Options
Include auto-update (-a): false
Include latest (-f): false
==> Updating Homebrew
Already up-to-date.
...
==> Found outdated apps
     Cask                       Current        Latest        A/U    Result
1/3  libreoffice                6.3.2          6.3.4              [OUTDATED]
2/3  libreoffice-language-pack  6.3.2          6.3.4              [OUTDATED]
3/3  virtualbox                 6.0.14,133895  6.1.0,135406       [OUTDATED]

Do you want to upgrade 3 apps or enter [i]nteractive mode [y/i/N]? y
==> Upgrading libreoffice to 6.3.4
==> Downloading ...
```

Comment: Good Walk Through

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today with docker desktop and found this: https://docs.brew.sh/FAQ#why-arent-some-apps-included-during-brew-upgrade

So if you are using the `latest` version of software *(or)* with own update functionality, you either need to

- use the built-in update functionality (firefox, iterm2, docker, telegram etc)
- use `brew upgrade <cask>` or
- use `brew upgrade --greedy`

I think using yet another tool to do this is unnecessary, but that's up to you.